# How to catch CTRL+S key in Excel 2010/2013/2016 Add-In

Tags: macros, vsto, excel-addins

I have a legacy Office 2007 Add-In where the user32.dll SetWindowsHookEx based custom function is used to intercept <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> key press event on a thread and do a customised file save. The function works fine in Windows7 but does not in Office 2016 and Windows10 environment. I don't know how to fix this bug.

So, I tried another approach to intercept <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>. I used `ThisAddIn.Application.OnKey("^{s}", "MySaveMethod")` function with a macro programmatically imported into an active workbook. This approach works.  But, the company's Group Policy requires to sign all macros added to a workbook and it seems impossible to sign a macro programmatically.

I wonder what other developers do to catch key press event or develop a keyboard shortcut in their Excel 2010/2013/2016 Add-In's? Any ideas are much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered `Workbook_BeforeSave` event?  You can code this in an Addin by using an Application Event handler ([see CPearson.com for details](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx) )

Comment: Thank you, Chris you for you advise. I tried to use BeforeSave event and it catches the  CTRL+S well. The problem in my case is a Workbook.Save method is called in the custom save code. This method fires the BeforeSave event and I have kind of infinite logic loop because the program control gets back to the CTRL+S interceptor where the custom save code is called from. I'm trying to figure out  how I can detect whether the BeforeSave event was triggered by Workbook.Save method in order to ignore it in the CTRL+S interceptor.

Answer (score 1):

Try using repurpose commands.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb462633(v=office.12).aspx

In your ribbon add these

```
<commands> 
 <command idMso="FileSave" onAction="mySave" /> 
</commands>
```

In ribbon.cs

```
public void mySave(IRibbonControl control, bool cancelDefault)
{
    //Do whatever you want
    //Don't forget to save manually
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Kiru for your advise. I will try it soon and will let you know whether it works for me.

Comment: I've looked in the code and found out that this approach was already implemented in this application before I started my changes. Apparently, it did not work. The solution for me was to use  Workbook_BeforeSave  event handler and document custom property. I created document custom property to use it as an indicator that BeforeSave event was triggered from inside Workbook.Save or Workbook.SaveAs method.

Comment: The custom property was analysed in Workbook_BeforeSave  code in order to stop recursive call of custom Save function. The indicator custom property was set up to true just before the Workbook.Save call and to false right after the call.         Thank you, Kiru and Chris, for your helpful ideas.